# Phoenix.HTML.Form and formatting a Timex.DateTime for a text input

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to alter the format of a Timex DateTime field to a single text input. When I let Phoenix take care of the formatting, it looks like this:

`2017-04-06 23:03:44.513454+10:00 AEST Australia/Hobart`

Note that I'm using `use Timex.Ecto.Timestamps, usec: true` - so it includes the microseconds.

Here's what I would like it to look like:

`2017-04-06 23:03:44 +10:00`

Is there a way to control the format of the date via the form `text_input` tag? Or is there another way to do this?

Here's the schema I'm using:

```
schema "log" do
  field :start_date, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
  field :end_date, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
  field :comment, :string

  timestamps
end
```

My form looks something like this:

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Oops, something went wrong! Please check the errors below.</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :start_date, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :start_date, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :start_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :end_date, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :end_date, class: "form-control" %>

    <%= error_tag f, :end_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :comment, class: "control-label" %>
    <%= textarea f, :comment, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :comment %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How about `text_input f, :start_date, class: "form-control", value: %{input_value(f, :start_date) | microsecond: {0, 0}}`?

Comment: ex(9)> Timex.format!(Timex.now(), "%F %T %:z", :strftime)  => 
   "2017-04-19 15:44:01 +00:00"

Comment: I didn't realise that `input_value` existed. That's solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the input's value using `Phoenix.HTML.Form.input_value/2` and you can specify the value to show to the user by passing `value: ...` to `text_input`. Combine this with removing the microseconds from the value and you'll get the time in the same format without any microseconds:

```
text_input f, :start_date, class: "form-control", value: %{input_value(f, :start_date) | microsecond: {0, 0}}
```